# On the subgroups of $\mu_{p^{\infty}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and $\mu_{p^{\infty}}$ denote $$\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \exists k \ge 1 : z^{p^k}=1 \}$$ find all of its subgroups.

I was able to prove that its finite subgroups are of the form $\mu_{p^n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer (using Lagrange's Theorem and the fact that in, $\mu_{\infty}=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \exists k \ge 1 : z^k=1 \} $, a subgroup of order $n$ is $\mu_n=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} : z^n=1\}$). However I am struggling to find its infinite subgroups, if there are any. Any hints on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This group, the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group), has no proper infinite subgroup.

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup. Consider the set 
$$
E_{H} = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : \text{in $H$ there is an element of order $p^{k}$} \}.
$$
If $E_{H}$ is infinite, then $H$ is the whole group. If $E_{H}$ is finite, and $K$ is its maximum, then $H$ is a a cylic group of order $p^{K}$.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Andreas Caranti's answer, consider a sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots\in\mathbb N$ so that we have the subgroup

$$H=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\mu_{p^{a_k}},$$
(where any subgroup $H\leq \mu_{p^\infty}$ can be written in such a way) then since for any $k\leq a_j$ we have $\mu_{p^{k}}\leq\mu_{p^{a_j}}$, then for any $n$ we have 
$$\mu_{p^n}=\bigcup_{k=1}^n\mu_{p^k}$$
from which it follows that 
$$H=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\mu_{p^{a_k}}=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{i=1}^{a_k}\mu_{p^i}=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\mu_{p^k}=\mu_{p^\infty}.$$